# Regexp: Match multiple line pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regexp that matches a pattern that spreads across multiple lines. For example I need to take the first git commit of a specific author.

I know that there is a way in doing this using git but I want it in regexp.

```
commit 9a06fd844952587774632f470442288e422910da
Author: Mark Gitter <mark.gitter@microsoft.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 11 17:13:26 2013 +0300

    Random git comment.
```

This regexp `commit [a-z0-9]*` matches the commit sha-1 but I can't get it start searching on the next line.
I'm testing it in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

I want it to match

```
commit 9a06fd844952587774632f470442288e422910da
Author: Mark Gitter
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to get to the next line. For example I would expect `commit [a-z0-9]*\nAuthor` to match `commit 9a06fd844952587774632f470442288e422910da
Author` but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're on Windows. Seems like it contains `\r`. Use `\s+` to make it more robust. `commit ([a-z0-9]{40})\s+Author`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\r\n` for new line:

```
commit (.*)\r\nAuthor:(\s*\w+\s*\w+)
```

Comment: yea, the problem was the line return. I found `commit (.*)[(\r)|(\n)|(\r\n)]Author:(\s*\w+)` to be pretty cross platform...

Comment: For me this only captured the author's first name.

Comment: It will capture just the first name, my main purpose was to show how to handle the new line character , However i am updating the answer to capture the whole name

Comment: @JasonSwartz: You probably want `(\r\n|\r|\n)`. Your version will include `|` and `()` in the character class.

Answer (score 2):

Since some of the Author names contain spaces we can capture everything up to the `<` sign, not including a the preceding space.

```
commit ([a-z0-9]*)\s*Author:(\s*[^<]+)(?<!\s)
```

Here's the [proof of concept](http://regexr.com?356qj).